# Comparing and updating two large tables

Tags: postgis, carto

I'm using CartoDB to sync the status from tables using a common ID on each one. The problem I found it's the tables are too large, over 29k rows.

Here is the query I'm using and the gives me an error.

```
SELECT tab1 SET status=tab2.status FROM tab2 WHERE tab1.id=tab2.id;
```

Is there any workaround to handle large comparison and updates for large tables?

Comment: What is the error? I regularly have to do update joins with many millions of rows in Postgres, and sometimes you have to fiddle to get the right query plan, but 29k is not very large and shouldn't cause any problem.

Comment: Probably stupid question, but both ids are primary keys, I take it?

Comment: Barça is right, there isn't a good reason why 29k rows would time out. What is the error reported? Creating a couple indexes here could help anyway.

Comment: Probably I described the problem wrong. My intention is to update the status if the value of tab1.status is different from the value in tab2.status.

Comment: To avoid unecessary work, you can add to you where clause,`SELECT tab1 SET status=tab2.status FROM tab2 WHERE tab1.id=tab2.id and tab1.status!=tab2.status;` But you still aren't saying what error you get?